# Wait Until Browser Has Loaded Page, Clear Cache

Tags: android

I am trying to write an android app to test performance and battery life of a phone.  I am trying to do the following:

```
//start timing
//open browser to web page (using intent)
//wait for browser to finish loading page
//stop timing
//calculate total time, write to file
//clear browser cache
//repeat until battery dies
```

My questions is, how can I tell when the page has loaded?  I have seen a few mentions of javascript, but I haven't seen a good example to understand how I can integrate that into my app (or even if that is the best idea for what I want to accomplish).

My second question is, how can I clear the browser's cache?  Preventing the browser from loading from cache is also a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a progress view that displays until the page has loaded. This is accomplished by:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            //are we done yet?
            if(progress == 100) {               
                try
                {
                    View progress_bar =(View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
                    //hide the progress view if we are done
                    if(progress_bar != null)
                        progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT: I have not tested this but have you tried the following to disable caching:

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I *assumed* this was for a webview, after reading @CommonsWare  this may not be the case. Use my answer if you decide to use a WebView.

Comment: I was hoping to use the browser, but it looks like this might not be possible, so I'll look into using a WebView.

Comment: Ok well if either @CommonsWare or my own answer is of use please tick them as useful/upvote for others to use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I tell when the page has loaded?

You are welcome to note this manually.

If you think you are going to automate this process, that is not possible, because the browser is not your app.

> how can I clear the browser's cache?

You are welcome to clear it manually, either within the browser itself (if the browser has an option for that), or via the Applications portion of the Settings app.

If you think you are going to automate this process, that is not possible, because the browser is not your app.

> Preventing the browser from loading from cache is also a possible solution.

You are welcome to configure that manually in whatever browser it happens to be that you are testing, assuming the browser in question has a configuration option for that.

If you think you are going to automate this process, that is not possible, because the browser is not your app.

Now, it is conceivable that some browser happens to offer APIs to allow you to accomplish all of the above automatically. The stock Browser app from the open source project does not, and I am unaware of any that does (and would be scared if one did).

You are also welcome to use the WebView widget in your own app, in which case you can automate all this stuff, because that's *your* app.